# githook to validate newly created branch names

Tags: git, githooks

Does anyone know if there's a githook that will hook into the creation of a branch in order to reject the branch name before it's actually created?

I currently use commit-msg to validate the branch name upon commits, but i'm looking for a way to avoid having to rename a branch if it doesn't match our policy (regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not (and to some extent it can't be controlled: branch names are transferred across the network during fetch and push, via refspecs, and refspecs are somewhat limited).

There *is* a git command, `git check-ref-format`; its [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ref-format.html) describes what *Git* allows.  (Branch names are simply any reference that starts with `refs/heads/`.)

Comment: yeah, I was ok with not being able to control all branch names all the times, but I figured if I could check on `git checkout, or git branch` the results would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if there's a githook that will hook into the creation of a branch in order to reject the branch name before it's actually created?

The only place you can mandate anything at all is in your own repositories.  In your pre-receive exit,

```
while read old new ref; do 
    yourtesthere "$ref" || { rc=1; echo "$ref failed yourtesthere's validation"; }
done
exit $rc
```

and no one can push a bad refname to your repository.  A command to check a name before passing it along to git is down in alias / oneliner territory.

You can distribute the `yourtesthere` command, of course, and anyone that wants can use it to test branch names in their own repositories, but just as your repositories are yours, their repositories are theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are referring to placing a policy for commits or branch creation.
There is a git config command which helps in putting some template in place
eg:

$ git config --global commit.template ~/.template.txt
$ git commit

subject line

what happened

[ticket: X]

```
# Please enter the commit message .......
#
# modified:   lib/test.rb
#
~
~
".git/COMMIT_EDITMSG"
```

Sorry if this did not help. Thanks.